# angular pipe - how to transform multiple types to another unique one?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have a component with two list of data products and author (for the sample)

**list-card-Component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list-card',
    templateUrl: 'list-card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['list-card.component.scss'],
})
export class ListCardComponent {
    @Input() products: Product[];
    @Input() authors: Author[];


    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Author and Product are define as following

```
export class Author {
    name: string;
    biography: string;
}

export class Product {
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

I also have an external module (installed by npm) with a card component that display a title and text according to a config send to him as input

```
export class CardConfig {
    title: string;
    text: string;
}
```

**card.component.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['card.component.scss'],
  })
  export class CardComponent {
    @Input() config: CardConfig;
  
  
    constructor() {
    }
  }
```

card.component.component.html

```
  <div class="card">
    <h2>{{config.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{config.text}}</p>
  </div>
```

I can t modify the card component

My issue is i want to be able to use product or author displayed in the card

list-card-Component.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div *ngFor="let product of products">
        <card [config]="product | toCardConfig"></card>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Author</h1>
<div *ngFor="let author of authors">
    <card [config]="author | toCardConfig"></card>
</div>
</div>
```

for this i start working on a pipe to transform a data into CardConfig

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'toCardConfig',
    pure: false
  })
  export class CardConfigPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: (Product | Author)): CardConfig {
      let type: string = typeof data;
      switch (type) {
        case 'Product':
          data = (data as Product);
          return {
              title: data.name,
              text: data.description
          }
        case 'Author':
            data = (data as Author);
            return {
                title: data.name,
                text: data.biography
            }
      return data;
    }
}
```

Is this a good aproach or is there another one ?

how can i perform similar process with generic type `T` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the use of a pipe here.

You could simply use @Input() in your card.

```
  export class CardComponent {
    @Input() set config(value :Author | Product) {
      if (value instanceof Author) 
        this.data = { name: value.name, text: data.biography };
      else if (value instanceof Product)
        this.data = { name: value.name, text: data.description };
    }
  
    data?: CardConfig;
  }
```

A pipe should be used to transform data for directly displaying i (like rounding numbers, or uppercasing strings). I don't really see the point of using a pipe here, it only overloads your code

Comment: Unfortunately i can t modify card component its embed inside an external module installed by npm. We choose to create a pipe to not polluate our component controller with a function for data transformation

Comment: I hope the card component is not just that piece of code then :) but in that case, I think the pipe is kind of suited for your need !

Comment: Also, feel free to use the code I gave with "instanceof", which is way more concise than yours !

Comment: No indeed the card component contain a lot of more code for functional usage

Comment: after reorganized our project we are able to use your reply. it's work as needed thank you for your reply